# PHP fsockopen image upload

Tags: php, sockets, upload

I'm trying to make a socket post with PHP, which doesn't seem to work properly:

```
$sCRLF = "\r\n";
$sBoundary = "------".md5(time())."------".$sCRLF;
$_HEAD = $_CONTEXT['vars']['sMethod']." ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sPage']." ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sHTTP'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Host: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sHost'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "User-Agent: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sAgent'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Accept: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sAccept'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Accept-Language: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sAcceptLanguage'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Accept-Encoding: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sAcceptEncoding'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Accept-Charset: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sAcceptCharSet'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Connection: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sConnection'].$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Referer: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sReferer'].$sCRLF;
if(isset($_CONTEXT['vars']['sCookie']) && !empty($_CONTEXT['vars']['sCookie'])){
    $_HEAD .= "Cookie: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sCookie'].$sCRLF;
}
$_HEAD .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sVarUpload']."\"; filename=\"".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sFileName']."\"".$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Content-Type: ".$_CONTEXT['vars']['sMedia']."; boundary= ".$sBoundary.$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary".$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".$sCRLF.$sCRLF;
$_HEAD .= readfile($sDest);
$rConnect = @fsockopen($_CONTEXT['vars']['sHost'],80,$errno,$errstr,30);
if($rConnect){
    fwrite($rConnect,$_HEAD);
    while(!feof($rConnect)){
        echo fgets($rConnect,128);
    }
    fclose($rConnect);
}
```

I do get a response, 200 OK and the html form, but if I dump $_FILES and/or $_POST I get an empty array. So apparently the variabels don't get send at all. I tried changing the headers but I keep on getting the same results. I don't have acces to cUrl sadly so that's no option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any reason you're socket-based stuff instead of just using `curl` or a `stream`? curl would reduce all of that down to about 5 lines of code. As well, for a file upload, you should be using `multipart/form-data` the upload.

Comment: http://php.net/readfile - why do add an integer number after the headers? And have you tried as well changing the color-balance of your monitor? :) (you are probably looking for http://php.net/file_get_contents instead)

Comment: Like @MarcB wrote, I can not see at all that you are using the transfer encoding that is used for neither $_FILES and/or $_POST so therefore as this is not asking in concrete, I vote to put this on hold to give this some room to be improved.